# Strange prediction's output (OCR CRNN)

Tags: image, machine-learning, testing, ocr, prediction

I use CRNN (CNN+RNN+CTCLoss) for my OCR. My dataset is 10000 image-text (7000 training+valid and 3000 testing)

examples:
[image: examples of dataset]

My architecture is inspired by VGG-16, I'm using 13 conv layers and 3 bi-directional LSTM Layer and I am using CTC Loss. 
Here is my architecture (training):

[image: training architecture]

here's my training's result:
batch_size = 256
epochs = 50
[image: training's result]

I don't know why but my output only predicted 'p' character for all my dataset.

[image: testing]

I can't put in here all my code, so you all can see my code here:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Mio5i6ySlSPnSs1o1sc-WpgfYLu9i9iy?usp=sharing

QUESTIONS: why my predictions is only 'p'? is it because of my dataset is not that much or because of my architecture? And how I can reduce my Loss ??? thanks

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I saw your code, I realized that your code is almost similar to the one found here: https://github.com/its-jd/A-CRNN-model-for-Text-Recognition-in-Keras or here:
https://github.com/TheAILearner/A-CRNN-model-for-Text-Recognition-in-Keras

If you are using someone's code then **please don't forget to give credits to the original posts.**

*Now lets solve your problem,*

You have 7000 training images which is very less to train  a model with millions of parameters and on top of that, your loss is about ~19 which is very high. So your models didn't learn anything in this training. For this particular problem, your loss should be around ~ 0.5 (I have trained the model in above git repo, so based on my experience I am saying this)

As your model has different dimensions, you will not be able to use pre-trained weights found in above github repos. So, there are two possible ways:

1. *Trouble some and time consuming:* Train your model with synthtext and then fine tune with your dataset (while fine tuning keep your learning rate very small as you dont want to blow up everything)
2. *Easy:* Use the direct model found in above githubb repos and fine tune them with your dataset. For this, first you have to resize your dataset to have height less than 128 pixels. But I am sure, this will give better results!

Happy training:)